# Problem migrating Maven project to Gradle

Tags: maven, gradle

I have been trying to migrate a maven project I developed to gradle. I have encountered the following error when running

```
./gradlew clean build
```

Below is the error I am getting

```
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
> Could not resolve com.fasterxml:classmate:1.3.4.
 Required by:
     project : > org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.1.1.RELEASE > org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:6.0.13.Final
     project : > org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:2.1.1.RELEASE > org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.3.7.Final
  > Could not resolve com.fasterxml:classmate:1.3.4.
     > Could not get resource 'http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/classmate/1.3.4/classmate-1.3.4.pom'.
        > Could not HEAD 
'http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/classmate/1.3.4/classmate-1.3.4.pom'. 
Received status code 501 from server: HTTPS Required
> Could not resolve net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:1.8.17.
 Required by:
     project : > org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:2.1.1.RELEASE > org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.3.7.Final
  > Skipped due to earlier error
  > Could not resolve org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-annotations-api:9.0.13.
 Required by:
     project : > org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:2.1.1.RELEASE > org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:9.0.13
  > Skipped due to earlier error
```

Below is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>project</groupId>
<artifactId>FantasyAnalysis</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>FantasyAnalysis Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    </dependency> 
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
    <artifactId>bootstrap-datepicker</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
    <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>   
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
</dependency>   
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.7</version>
</dependency>   
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
<finalName>FantasyAnalysis</finalName>
<plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Below is my build.gradle

```
plugins {
id 'java'
id 'maven'
id 'war'
}

repositories {
mavenLocal()
maven {
    url = 'http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2'
}
}

dependencies {
compile 'org.springframework:spring-webmvc:5.1.3.RELEASE'
compile 'org.springframework:spring-context:5.1.3.RELEASE'
compile 'org.springframework:spring-context-support:5.1.3.RELEASE'
compile 'org.springframework:spring-beans:5.1.3.RELEASE'
compile 'org.springframework:spring-jdbc:5.1.3.RELEASE'
compile 'org.springframework:spring-test:5.1.3.RELEASE'
compile 'org.springframework:spring-core:5.1.3.RELEASE'
compile 'org.springframework:spring-orm:5.1.3.RELEASE'
compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.1.1.RELEASE'
compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:2.1.1.RELEASE'
compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:2.1.1.RELEASE'
compile 'org.webjars:bootstrap-datepicker:1.0.1'
compile 'org.webjars:jquery:1.9.1'
compile 'javax.mail:javax.mail-api:1.6.2'
compile 'javax.mail:mail:1.4.7'
runtime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools:2.1.1.RELEASE'
runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.13'
runtime 'com.h2database:h2:1.4.197'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
testCompile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:2.1.1.RELEASE'
testCompile 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test:5.1.2.RELEASE'
providedCompile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'
providedCompile 'javax.servlet:jstl:1.2'
providedCompile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:2.1.1.RELEASE'
providedCompile 'org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper:9.0.13'
}
group = 'project'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
description = 'FantasyAnalysis Maven Webapp'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}
```

Any ideas as to how to fix the error? I am new to gradle and don't have much experience with it. Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used the following repo:

```
http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/
```

The error clearly says that https is required:

> `Received status code 501 from server: HTTPS Required`

Use the following instead:

```
https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/
```

Note that this repo is referred to as Maven Central, and gradle has a shortcut for it: [Declaring repositories - Maven Central](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html#sub:maven_central)

Comment: Thanks for this, The project now builds succesfully. By any chance do you know how I would proceed to run this on localhost? When using `./gradlew run` I am getting an error saying task run is not found

Comment: I can see yo’re using spring boot. I suggest getting faimiliar with spring boot gradle plugin. For your particular question: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.5.RELEASE/gradle-plugin/reference/html/#running-your-application

Comment: Thanks. Does this pluging require a main() class? Since my project does not have one.

Comment: Do you want to run it in place or in external tomcat? How did you do this with maven. Spring boot gradle plugin is more or less equivalent to spring boot maven plugin you used before.

Comment: I want to run in tomcat in my machine. Yeah it works when I run it on server on spring however not to sure how to achieve the same with gradle.

Comment: I would encourage you to use embedded tomcat in development if you are already using spring boot. It is easy to make an app that can be run both as a standalone jar and as a war: https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-with-external-tomcat

Comment: What is embedded tomcat?